# How to fix debugging shortcut key to work on Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I use `Visual Studio 2010 Professional` to code programs in C and C++.
Initially I had issues with running the program with `F5` as the console would directly pop-up and disappear. Then I found the solution to it was `ctrl+F5` and it works fine.
But if I want to debug a program line by line using the debug operations `Step-Into` and  `Step Over`  shortcut keys F11 and F10 respectively, they won't work. Instead F11 will decrease my display brightness.
What should I do to fix this? Please help me with a suitable solution to this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Options. Select Environment -> Keyboard from the tree on the left. Write Debug in "Show commands containing" to filter the commands. Scroll to Debug.StepInto and in the text box where it says "Press shortcut keys:" press F11 then click Assign button.
Do the same for Step Over.